# Double slit and measuring polarization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, double-slit-experiment, polarization

If you make the double slits experiment and you measure the path the photon went through the wave function will instantly collapse

But if you measure the polarity of the photons without measuring the path. Will the function collapse just because you messed with the photons or as you don't have the path information will it retains its wave function?

Comment: "the wave function will instantly collapse" that would violate causality.

Comment: well ... not "instantly" it was a speached pattern poorly chosen for a physics question but I meant the wave function will collapse if you measure the path the photon went through